# are these two linq expressions functionally equivalent?

Tags: c#, linq

is there any functional difference between:

```
if (photos.Any(it => it.Archived))
```

and

```
if (photos.Where(it => it.Archived).Any())
```

if so, is there a more compelling reason to use one over the other?

Comment: The results of this should be the same, but since I'm not 100% sure about if there is any performance differences, I'll let this one go and let someone with a definitive answer on this post it.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can investigate the IL yourself. Please a breakpoint in the funktion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functionally they do the same thing. The performance depends on the specific provider, but for example in LINQ to SQL both forms produce the exact same SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [dbo].[photos] AS [t0]
            WHERE [t0].[Archived] = 1
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
```

If I have to pick one I'd use the first option as it seems slightly more clear to me.

Comment: +1 for the hint that the actual implementation is up to the provider.

Comment: @Tim Jarvis: Thanks. I reworded it from just a "hint" to make it a little more explicit that it is provider specific.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference *practical difference* for the current .NET Framework implementation of the methods. Because of deferred execution, both will enumerate `photos` until it finds a match, and then stop. (Provided that this is Linq-to-objects - other providers might behave different).

If you want to get nit-picky, there are small implementational differences. (You can look it up in the framework sources):

`Any` simply iterates the collection using foreach, where as `Where` returns either a `WhereArrayIterator`, `WhereListIterator`, or a `WhereEnumerableIterator` depending on what type of collection you pass in. I haven't looked into this in depth, but I would guess that this is done in order to allow chained extension methods to optimize in case of an array or list is used.

In other words, where `Any` contains a simple `foreach`, `Where` does this:

```
    if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate); 
    if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
    return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
```

Comment: I thought any threw a ArgumentNullException if given a null predicate as would be the case in the second version, but then I don't use LINQ all that much.

Comment: The issue isn't deferred execution, it is lazy evaluation. Yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 2):

As an expression, they produce the same result. However, the mechanism that produces this result is slightly different. Note though that they both walk through the same number of items from the original sequence.

I would always use the former as it is shorter and there is no loss of clarity, readability nor maintainability in choosing it over the second.